# Uploading a file in Laravel

Tags: php, upload, laravel

Helllo, Hello

I am trying to upload a file at Laravel. However when I am at the controller, whatever method that tries to contact the object complains that it is not such an object and it cannot get its properties.

I have three fields, category, title and content, and then the file itself. I have searched here and there is some complicated code for uploading multiple files and then what resembles mine, yet without approved answers.

I also dont understand how the process is, I am just imagining it. I mean, one method can actually place the file in a folder in the server but I also need its path to be stored in the table of the database. I dont know that that actually happens, I read the documentation in Laravel docs and this is below what I have.

```
$category = Input::get('category');
$title = Input::get('title');
$content = Input::get('content');
$thefile = Input::file('fichero');
$filename = Input::file($thefile)->getClientOriginalName();
$destinationPath = "etc etc://../laravel/cosas";
Input::file('fichero')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
$path = Input::file('fichero')->getRealPath();
```

Then this is what I should be sending to the Model, (just by intuition, never did it before)

```
(new document)->insertDocs($category, $title, $content, $path);
```

Does anyone know how this is done?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller :

```
public function store()
{
    // Upload file
    $file = Input::file('fichero');
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/folder';
    $file->move($destinationPath);

    // Create model
    $model = new Model;
    $model->category = Input::get('category');
    $model->title = Input::get('title');
    $model->content = Input::get('content');
    $model->filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $model->destinationPath = $destinationPath;

    // Save model
    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you. Excuse my terrible ignorance, I am trying very hard to learn very quickly. That what you have written is to be put in the controller? Then, there is no code to write in the Model itself? I dont need the model php file?

Comment: I ll give you the correct answer and will try it later.